# Is it possible to change the location of a virtual image without using moving lenses?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, image-processing

The benefit of a [head-up display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head-up_display) is primarily in reducing the time required by the user to refocus their eyes from the head-down display to the head-up surroundings. In applications such as [cars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automotive_head-up_display), the best focal length would be at infinity for driving on the highway. However for driving in the city, where the driver has to pay attention to events close to the wind-shield, a good location of the image would be closer than infinity. Is it possible to change the location of the virtual image in real-time for such head-up displays without using a moving lens?

Comment: You do not pay attention to something happening at wind-shield distance when driving in cities. Events happen at distance of 5 meters or more. Focusing at 5 meters is very close to focusing at infinity. The HUD at infinity will be most likely just fine.

Comment: Head-up displays (HUDs), for instance an iPad, can also consist of projecting images *at* the distance of the dashboard. However, if the idea is to provide conformal augmented reality imagery, the distance might be higher (~ 7.5 m to 20 m) as in this [white paper](http://www.ti.com/lit/wp/dlpa057a/dlpa057a.pdf). The question is whether, if required, it is possible to change the location of the virtual image without using moving lenses (by changing the properties of the image).

Comment: maybe you can use moving flat surface mirrors instead of moving lenses.

Comment: I would appreciate a concise reference on using the movement of flat surface mirrors to change the virtual image location. I don't follow the statement 'In the optics of an AR HUD, the virtual image distance can be controlled by a small translation of the diffuser screen relative to the HUD optics. For example, the virtual image may be shifted from10 m to 20 m by a small adjustment of the screen position which could be less than12 mm.', on page 5 of [the paper](http://www.ti.com/lit/wp/dlpa057a/dlpa057a.pdf).

Comment: Fig 1 in the paper does not shown where the diffuser screen is. Assume it is at where PGU is located. Then it is not hard to understand why a small movement of the screen can cause big movement of the virtual image. You can do an experiment by yourself. Find a curved mirror (very common for making ups; you can find them in stores selling makeups, in hair saloons, or Walmart), place an object near the mirror, and look at its image in the mirror. A small move of the object will cause a big move of the image.

Comment: Thanks @verdelite. I am not sure what the abbreviations PGU and ups stand for, but I broadly understand your explanation. Please add any thoughts on how the same task can be achieved by manipulating the image (say, a digital one), if possible.